# Rails create unique token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a token inside a controller and as you can see I don't want to create any duplicate tokens:

```
def generate_token
  loop do
    random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
    break random_token unless Product.exists?(uid: random_token)
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure that my code is correct and it will not create any duplicate tokens. But I just wanted to double check before I actually use it.

Comment: Rails has this built in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2):

```
random_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand(111..999)].join)
```

or
pass `SecureRandom.hex(32) in Digest::SHA1.hexdigest()`
So that way it will always unique.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @adityapandit17... what about the `break` part of the code, should I keep that?

Comment: Yes you can keep that..just for playing safe.
But here we don't need loop. 
Just generate the token

Comment: (1) Your initial proposed method is rather brittle as it predictably produces one of only 888 different values per second and can be brute-forced quickly. `SecureRandom` is the much better option most of the time. (2) It is unnecessary to pass the output of `SecureRandom.hex` through SHA1. This doesn't improve entropy in any way. Your proposal is results in similar data to just running `SecureRandom.hex(20)` (3) With all of your options, you can still have collisions theoretically. But the chance for a collision becomes neglectable for large random numbers such as `SecureRandom.hex(32)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a built in solution for this called [`has_secure_token`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_token)

```rb
# Schema: User(token:string, auth_token:string)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_token
  has_secure_token :auth_token, length: 36
end

user = User.new
user.save
user.token # => "pX27zsMN2ViQKta1bGfLmVJE"
```

Comment: How can we make sure that tokens are uniq? We can add uniq index but this can lead to raised exceptions